# Приложение вылетает при обращении к ImageView в методе onBindViewHolder класса RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android

Есть RecyclerView, который состоит из множества CardView,который, в свою очередь, содержит 2 ImageView и 1 TextView.
При обращении к методам TextView в методе onBindViewHolder(PlayerViewHolder holder, int position)  приложение работает стабильно, а при обращении к любому из ImageView, скажем, при попытке поставить background, приложение сразу же вылетает. Не понимаю, в чем причина этого...
Прикладываю код:

Класс моего Player:

```
public class Player implements Parcelable {
private int points;
private String name;
private String color;
private GradientDrawable shape;



public Player(String name, int points, String color) {

    this.name = name;
    this.points = points;
    this.color = color;
}



protected Player(Parcel in) {
    points = in.readInt();
    name = in.readString();
    color = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Player> CREATOR = new Creator<Player>() {
    @Override
    public Player createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Player(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Player[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Player[size];
    }
};

public void addPoint(){
    this.points++;
}
public String name(){
    return this.name;
}
public int points(){
    return this.points;
}
public String color(){return this.color;}



@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(points);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(color);
}
```

Класс моего RecyclerView.ViewHolder:

```
public class PlayerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

ImageView imageViewRoundBackground;
ImageView imageViewPlayerColor;
TextView textViewPoints;


public PlayerViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    imageViewRoundBackground = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewRoundBackground);
    imageViewPlayerColor = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewChangeColor);
    textViewPoints = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPoints);
}
```

Класс моего RecyclerView.Adapter

```
public class PlayerRoundDisplay extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayerViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

public PlayerRoundDisplay(ArrayList<Player> players){

    this.players = players;
}

@Override
public PlayerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.display_round_player, parent, false);
    PlayerViewHolder holder = new PlayerViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlayerViewHolder holder, int position) {
   holder.textViewPoints.setText(Integer.toString(players.get(position).points()));
    holder.imageViewPlayerColor.setImageResource(R.drawable.round_corner_add); //здесь возникает ошибка!

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return players.size();
}
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: а что написано в сообщении об ошибке?

Comment: Я компилю на реальном устройстве и не знаю, где смотреть ошибки :/

Comment: если в момент ошибки оно у вас подключено к Студии посмотрите в Android Monitor (вкладка снизу)

Comment: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Comment: добавьте в вопрос?

Comment: Что именно нужно добавить?

Comment: Ошибку) А вообще - попробуйте Instant Run отключить (если включен) File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run

Comment: Для чего это нужно?

Comment: Покажите полный стек-трейс.